# JAXB @XmlSeeAlso being overwritten

Tags: jaxb

I've defined a few types in a common.xsd I have multiple XSDs which have types that extend from the same type in common. When I generate the classes the @XmlSeeAlso attribute keeps getting updated to the most recent xsd being used.

Is it possible to tell the compiler that when the common class is generated there are more than one classes which can extend from it ?